# Display content of Text file on every boot Linux or DOS

Tags: linux, image, text, boot, display

I am looking for some one to direct me,

I have developed a software that automatically erase data from lan attached workstation's hard disk drives.  Once the data is erased storage device is emptied and there is nothing on the hdd. I am thinking about writing a text file on each hard drive that contains the hardware information such as hdd size, ram, processor and etc, this file will be placed on each hdd after successful wipe.

Wgen the workstation that was just wiped is booted each time, l want to display a data erasure report similar to this one on every boot, obliviously data is read from text file and displayed on every boot. I want to display logo and the text together so it will be combination of text and graphics.

The question is how i can display such information without installing full operating system.

Your help is appreciated.

This is an example of the data i want to display on each boot. Once the data is display system should be halted.

[image]

Comment: You mean like with DirectFB?

Comment: You will have to write code in assembly language that writes to screen using BIOS routines, INT 10 (if this is still valid in DOS/BIOS) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H. And put this code in boot sector of the disk.